# SSL Cert says its self-signed but decoding shows it's not

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, apache2, ssl-certificate-errors

I have a cert that is suddenly being presented as a self-signed cert.  Its not.  It has been working fine until now.  When I decode the cert it shows everything I would expect.  When I analyze it using an SSL Checker it says its self-signed.

How is this possible?

Comment: Was it issued by Symantec? As of Chrome v66, Symantec's CA is no longer trusted. https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/google-outlines-ssl-apocalypse-for-symantec-certificates/

Comment: @ceejayoz It was issued through GoDaddy.  I don't know if they resell Symantec certs.  But still, this happens regardless of the browser.

Comment: Other browser vendors followed suit (https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2018/03/12/distrust-symantec-tls-certificates/, https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO25850.html) - it was a coordinated response to Symantec screwing up enormously. Can you give us the domain so we can see the certificate and SSL check results?

Comment: Do you literally mean that it is *self-signed* (signed with it's own key, no chain of trust) or just untrusted? If it's self-signed it cannot possibly be the same cert you got signed by a CA (it is signed with it's own key, not the key of some CA). Can you show more information about what errors you get and/or what eg https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ says, or better yet share the URL and people can have a look for themselves?

Comment: Given that what you're saying isn't possible, there's some important information you're not telling us.  The easiest way to get useful answers will be to share the certificate and the exact errors you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to include a full certificate chain, instead of just the final cert.  You can just combine the intermediate certificates and CA certificates into one file.

i.e.:

```
cat yourcert.crt gd_intermediate.crt gd_bundle.crt > yourcert_bundle.crt
```

You can obtain GoDaddy's public certs (and intermediary certs) from their [public repo here](https://certs.godaddy.com/repository).